# Powershell Script for finding and replacing values in an XML file using a CSV file as parameters

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I've created a Powershell script which generates an XML file.  All the XML data is within the script and whatever items need to be repeated, I have them looped based on the amount of lines in the CSV (minus the header).

The next part of the script is where I'm having an issue.  Based on the same CSV, I'm trying now to modify the generated XML file and do a find and replace.  I generated which words need to be replaced from the loop such as FName1, FName2, FName3, LName1, LName2, LName3.

My problem here is that whenever I try to replace these words from the CSV file, nothing gets replaced unless I hard code FName1, FName2 and so on.

This is the code which I know is incorrect....  Basically  I want it to look for any instance of FName(1,2,3 etc) and LName(1,2,3 etc) and replace it with $`_.FirstNames and $`_.LastNames.

```
$c = Import-Csv test.csv

Get-ChildItem test.xml | Foreach-Object {
  $xmldoc = (Get-Content test.xml | Out-String)
  $i = 0
  $c | Foreach-Object {
    $xmldoc = $xmldoc -replace 'FName' + $i++,$_.FirstNames `
    -replace 'LName' + $i,$_.LastNames
  }

  $xmldoc | Set-Content test.xml
}
```

This is a portion of the test.xml file

```
<ItemRef ItemID="FName1" Mandatory="No"/>
<ItemRef ItemID="FName2" Mandatory="No"/>
<ItemRef ItemID="FName3" Mandatory="No"/>
<ItemRef ItemID="LName1" Mandatory="No"/>
<ItemRef ItemID="LName2" Mandatory="No"/>
<ItemRef ItemID="LName3" Mandatory="No"/>
```

And this is the test.csv file:

```
FirstNames,LastNames
John,Doe
Jane,Doe
Mike,Smith
Samantha,Fox
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Nas

Comment: I won't fix/improve your code because your approach is wrong. Unix shell/procedural mindset does not apply to Powershell. Think in terms of objects, their properties, methods. Do not process XML via _string find 'n replace_.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you incrementing your counter between `FName` and `LName`?
Instead of using `Get-Content` to read in your file, use `[IO.file]::ReadAllText()`. `[IO.file]::ReadAllText()` won't break the file into an array based on line breaks.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Powershell, but I'll google [IO.file]::ReadAllText() and try this out.  Thanks.

Comment: Tekno Sal has a good point. It would be better to use objects rather than strings.